# How to find everything inside a block except two case

Tags: javascript, regex

How to capture Fruits from the following pattern given that it doesnot contain
mango or grapes inside it ?

input:

```
<frutis>banana,apple,orrange,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,apple,mango,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,grapes,orrange,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,apple,orrange,guava</frutis>
```

output:
banana,apple,orrange,lichie
false
false
banana,apple,orrange,guava<

I have tried the following :

```
<frutis>([^mango|grapes]*)<\/frutis>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use negative look-ahead, like with this regular expression:

```
<frutis>(?!.*mango)(?!.*grapes).*<\/frutis>
```

As you wrote it, it does not work because classes `[.....]` are about matching single characters, not about sequences. Also, the pipe symbol has no special meaning inside a class, it just means the literal `|`.

Note: for matching data in XML structures it is not advised to use regular expressions, but a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<frutis>((?:(?!mango|grapes).)*)<\/frutis>
```

Source Code Here:

```
const regex = /<frutis>((?:(?!mango|grapes).)*)<\/frutis>/g;
const str = `<frutis>banana,apple,orrange,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,apple,mango,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,grapes,orrange,lichie</frutis>
<frutis>banana,apple,orrange,guava</frutis>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

I have used negative look ahead to detect if that two strings exist or not. 
Full explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/upnWce/1)